# c# wpf send E-Mail with gmail - the operation has timed out

Tags: c#, email, smtp, gmail

im trying to send an email from an gmail account but i always get the error- the operation has timed out.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezVMp.png)

tried different smtp clients (GMX, Google) same problem

Comment: You could try a web search

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please try to share code, errors, logs as TEXT in code fences or blocks but not as image.